# stl: временные затраты для добавления элементов в вектор

Tags: c++, оптимизация, vector, stl

Объясните пожалуйста откуда могут расти ноги во временных затратах при работе с добавлением в вектор:

есть следующие типы данных:

```
// элемент и совокупность элементов
using element_t = std::pair<int, int>;
using elements_t = std::vector<element_t>;

// ветка элементов
struct fork_t {
    elements_t sequence;
    int        weight;

    fork_t () {
         sequence.reserve(c_elements_count);
    }
};

// цепочка элементов
struct chain_t {
    fork_t     forks[2];
    int        weight;
};

// совокупность цепочек элементов
using chains_t = std::vector<chain_t>;
```

т.е. в общем то не очень сложные данные

в основном алгоритме происходит формирование цепочек (их меньше, чем элементов, которые входя в цепочки)

```
chains_t chains;
chains.reverse(c_chains_count);

for (...)
{
    // сразу добавляем цепочку, чтобы избежать лишнего копирования элементов
    chains.push_back(chain_t());
    auto& it = chains.back();

    // добавляем элементы
    add_elements(it);
}
```

внутри `add_elements` в цикле происходит добавление элементов

```
chain.fork[index].sequence.emplace_back(value1, value2);
```

**Так вот** когда посмотрел в профайлере, то оказалось, что на `chains.push_back(chain_t());` тратится в несколько раз больше времени, чем на все `emplace_back` внутри `add_elements`

При этом кол-во цепочек **гораздо** (в разы) меньше, чем кол-во элементов добавляемых в цепочки.

У меня по этому возник вопрос - а с чем такое поведение может быть связано?
Типы простые, каких-то сложных манипуляций с ними в конструкторах или где-то еще не происходит, тогда почему добавления пустых !!! цепочек для которых вызываются лишь 2 `reserve()` для каждой тратится так много времени?

Comment: Всё зависит от того, сколько памяти вы лишней просите. Точно пока невозможно вам сказать из-за отсутствии кода. Например если `c_elements_count` равен 1млн , то памяти будет зарезервировано очень много.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, прошу мало - c_elements_count - 100 (т.е. по сути 800 байт), цепочек не более 50ти (т.е.80400 байт)

Comment: кстати, товарищи, а за что минус в категории "Почему код не работает"? Код работает замечательно, мне интересна специфика выделения вычислительных ресурсов для контейнеров и почему происходит перекос в добавление элементов одних типов :)

Comment: каждый конструктор `chain_t()` - вызывает систему, чтобы она выделила вам память на два вектора. Выделение памяти вызывает большую паузу. Для скорости надо подумать об избавлении от `vector`. Создать собственный буфер один раз и его использовать.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, да у меня в голове были мысли уйти от вектора к обычным динамическим массивам и выделять память просто сразу на все цепочки разом. Отказался пока от этого потому что код станет менее понятным, а выигрыш будет скажем 10-20%, что не очень покупается на этапе разработки, поэтому думал, что временно можно обойтись полумерой - типа `reserve`, но видимо это все таки предел и раз от вектора мне нужно только добавить элемент/очистить вектор и пройтись по всем элементам, то можно свой легкий аналог сделать